# cli() call found in Rotary Encoder

Tags: c++, arduino

Found in the Arduino Cookbook page 202 `cli()` without reference or declaration. What does it mean or stand for please? As follows:

```
void loop ()
{
    Uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

    cli ();     /* What is this code please? */
    Pos = encoderPos;
    SREG = oldSREG;
    if (pos != oldPos)
    {...................
```

Comment: Try google: "arduino cli" or "arduino cli function". For me, the first result explains it: it disables interrupts.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your problem? Right now I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: I have answered your question, if you think its right please mark it with the green tick

Comment: This question should not be downvoted. There are tons of such questions for another languages where answer is also could be found in google.

Comment: @Joker And this on the other hand is no reason to upvote it. This question does not  show any research effort. It asks for being downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To disable interrupts:**

```
cli();                // disable global interrupts
```

**and to enable them:**

```
sei();                // enable interrupts
```

Note that the millis timer, and serial communication will be affected by disabling interrupts. The delayMicroseconds() function disables interrupts while it is running.

Comment: Thanks Victor now I do understand 'set' & 'clear' interrupt. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisSpreckley Hahahaha about time :P